# .NET Core 2.1 ConfigurationBuilder.Build() - StackOverflowException

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've installed VS 2017 Preview and [2.1.300-preview2-008530 SDK](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/04/11/announcing-net-core-2-1-preview-2/). Now, in my Web Application project following sequence generates StackOverflowException:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
```

NET Core 2.1 Preview 2 Known Issues - does not contain anything related to my problem.

Comment: would you add the stack trace?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add this package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.json

I ran into the same issue after upgrading to 2.1 and found this answer on microsoft online doc

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration

Comment: This should be check as the best answer.

Comment: Adding that package saved the day.  Thank you!